# Magento2.2.0 Community Edition Google Analytics Transaction Tracking issue

Tags: php, magento, google-analytics, magento2

I am using Magento 2.2.0 Community Edition for one of our projects.
We have implemented Google Tag Manager and Google Analytics as per the Magento2 Guidelines.

After few days we came to know that our transactions are working properly but Tag Manager is showing 2 times (in Google Chrome Add ON - Google Tag Assistant).

Because of this Google Tag Manager showing twice issue we have implemented the solution as given in this following link.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12221

Then tag manager is showing only one time but google transactions are not working.

We searched on this then we come to know that this issue has been fixed in Magento v 2.2.6. Hence we just copied their "google-analytics.js" file to our version 2.2.0 .

After that our google tag manager is showing only one time but still transaction is not been send to Google. The transaction tracking is completely stopped.
Is there any solution?
Is there any update for Magento v 2.2.0? Because we cannot upgrade our magento to latest one.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a custom success page? If so, you need to make sure that the google conversion tracking script is actually rolled out there and is provided with the correct values for the conversion. We had to manually load the codesnippet to the success page in order to get conversion tracking back up and running.